# Getting error 404 while trying to update a value in Rest API of Openhab using Python request.put

Tags: python, json, rest

I am trying to update a value in REST API of openhab using requests.put in Python. But I am getting error 404.

My code is copied below

```
import requests    
import json    
from pprint import pprint

TemperatureA_FF_Office = 20

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}    
payload = {'state' : TemperatureA_FF_Office}    
payld = json.dumps(payload)    
re = requests.put("http://localhost:8080/rest/items/TemperatureA_FF_Office
/state/put", params= payld, headers = headers)

pprint(vars(re))
```

The error code I am getting is

```
{'_content': '',    
 '_content_consumed': True,    
 'connection': <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 7fd3b55ec9d0>,    
 'cookies': <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>,    
 'elapsed': datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 4019),    
 'encoding': None,    
 'history': [],
 'raw': <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fd3b55ecd90>,    
 'reason': 'Not Found',    
 'request': <PreparedRequest [PUT]>,    
 'status_code': 404,    
 'url': u'http://localhost:8080/rest/items/TemperatureA_FF_Office/state/put?state=21.0'}
```

Is this the way to use requests.put? Please help.

Comment: Could you format better your code? It is not very easy to read it; you surely would get more answers after that. Regards.

Comment: check your url  pointing to api..

Comment: Use your browser to make sure if the url is not found : http://localhost:8080/rest/items/TemperatureA_FF_Office
/state/put

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
import requests
req = "http://localhost:8080/rest/items/YOUR_SENSOR_HERE/state"
val = VARIABLE_WITH_YOUR_SENSOR_DATA
try:
    r = requests.put(req,data=val)
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    r = "Response Error"
    print e
print r
```

This is a massively simplified version of what I'm using for some of my presence detection and temperature scripts.

The printing of 'r' and 'e' is useful for debug purposes and can be removed once you've got your script working properly.